# Renaming a date formated file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have a file which has current date as it's name, I want to rename that file but I am unable to do so, can somebody help me?

Current file name : `19062206.xlsx` *(yyddmm06)*

New file name : `19062206 TAS.csv`

Code : `rename.bat`

```
@echo off 
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "E:\Files\%%g%%f%%e06.xlsx" %%g%%f%%e06 TAS.csv
pause
```

Updated for further advice:

```
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null') Do @Set "ds=%%A%%B%%C" & GoTo Break
@Pause
:Break
@If Exist "E:\HCA_Automation\Files\%ds:~2%06.xlsx" Ren "E:\HCA_Automation\Files\%ds:~2%06.xlsx" "%ds:~2%06 TAS.xlsx"
Pause
```

Comment: Is the `06` filename suffix static? or is it there to represent any two, _(or more)_, digits? Is the script for running only on your PC with its current settings? or should it be able to function on any PC regardless of its user or locale settings?

Comment: @Compo, yes 06 is the filename suffix static... It should be able to function on any PC rgardless of its user or local settings

Comment: What happens instead when you run that code? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work for you.

```bat
@PushD "E:\HCA_Automation\Files" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
@For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null') Do @Set "ds=%%A%%B%%C" & GoTo Break
:Break
@If Exist "%ds:~2%06.xlsx" If Not Exist "%ds:~2%06 TAS.csv" Ren "%ds:~2%06.xlsx" "%ds:~2%06 TAS.csv"
@PopD
```

**[Edit /]**

The following example uses [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to retrieve yesterdays date in the format you require, and performs the same task as the [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) example above:

```bat
@PushD "E:\HCA_Automation\Files" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
@For /F %%A In ('PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyddMM')"'
) Do @If Exist "%%A06.xlsx" If Not Exist "%%A06 TAS.csv" Ren "%%A06.xlsx" "%%A06 TAS.csv"
@PopD
```

Comment: Hey, need one more help. Can you help me in letting me know that how can i modify the above code so that I can rename the previous day file ?

Comment: Unfortunately batch is not the best scripting language to use for date arithmetic because it works only with strings, not date objects. In order to more easily deal with date objects, I would suggest that you leverage another built-in scripting language. The answer above has been edited to cover your new request, _which should have been asked as a new question_, by utilising [tag:powershell].

Comment: Hey, when I am trying to execute the above code it just opens a powershell with a message "Press any key to continue".

Comment: @Begginer, I'm not sat at your computer, and I'm not trying to debug what you've done for something as simple as copying and pasting some code into a new `.cmd`/`.bat` file. This code is tested as working on your target Operating System, Windows 10, and is the same code I use in earlier Operating Systems too. *As I have already stated, this should have been a new question, so I am not motivated to provide additional support beyond the scope of the already answered question.*